# VSCode C++ Folding with Member Initializer Lists

Tags: visual-studio-code, folding

Currently Using VS Code with C++.

I have this code here:

```
Test::Test()
    : varA{0}, varB{1}
{

}
```

that I want to collapse into the code like so:

```
Test::Test()
```

But it only lets me collapse the code if I remove `, varB{1}` from the code block. Does the C++ folding strategy not work well with member initializer lists?